# will onLoad always be fired after DOM ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I want to disable some specific "feature" that one my plugins does to the DOM when the DOM is ready.

If I put my code inside the `onload` callback, will it always get executed after the `ready` callback?

I want to be sure in 100% that even if there aren't any images of just few the ready will be executed before the onload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I think [@jAndy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9249298/1106925) is right, you can afford yourself some extra assurance by also placing the code in the `onload` within a `ready()` call.

Just make sure that your main `ready()` call comes first.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your normal ready handler
});

$(window).load(function() {
    // Placing code in another .ready() call in here will add it to the
    //    end of internal Array of ready handlers if any are pending
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // my onload code
    });
});
```

So if the `ready()` has already fired by the time the `onload` fires, your `onload` code will still run. *(An internal flag is set once the DOM is ready, so future `.ready()` calls are immediately invoked.)*

If the `.ready()` has somehow *not* fired when the `onload` happens, that will mean that your original `ready()` code is first in the internal Array, and the new `.ready()` code will be added to the end of the Array.

---

**EDIT:**

Looking [at the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L400-403) for the main `jQuery.ready` handler that is fired when the DOM is ready *(which in turn, fires the list of the user's `.ready()` handlers)*, it appears as though there's an IE bug where the handler fires a little early.

To remedy this bug, jQuery makes the handler *asynchronously* invoked until it can actually see `document.body`.

```js
ready: function (wait) {
    // Either a released hold or an DOMready/load event and not yet ready
    if ((wait === true && !--jQuery.readyWait) || (wait !== true && !jQuery.isReady)) {

        // Make sure body exists, at least, in case IE gets a little overzealous (ticket #5443).
        if (!document.body) {
            return setTimeout(jQuery.ready, 1);
        }

        // Remember that the DOM is ready
        jQuery.isReady = true;

        // If a normal DOM Ready event fired, decrement, and wait if need be
        if (wait !== true && --jQuery.readyWait > 0) {
            return;
        }

        // If there are functions bound, to execute
        readyList.fireWith(document, [jQuery]);

        // Trigger any bound ready events
        if (jQuery.fn.trigger) {
            jQuery(document).trigger("ready").off("ready");
        }
    }
},
```

It would seem that because of this asynchronous looping of the handler, then IE would at least be possibly prone to having the `window.onload` handler invoked before the `.ready()` handlers.

Adding to the `.ready()` handler list within the `onload` as I described above should remedy this.

Comment: @gdoron: Taking a quick [look at the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L400-403), it appears as though there's an IE bug where the native DOM ready fires a little early. To resolve this, jQuery asynchronously loops its main `jQuery.ready` function until it sees the `document.body`. Because this is asynchronous, it would seem that there would be a very real chance that the `onload` could happen first. All that to say that placing your code in the `.ready()` as I've shown is probably going to be your safest bet. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- `onload` will fire when anything else was loaded (images, frames, iframes, etc.),
- `DOMContentLoaded` will fire as soon as the DOM tree can get accessed.

Comment: And if don't any images or there are just few? I want to be sure in 100%

Comment: @gdoron: well I can't find any "official" spec or documentation about event order currently. But I'm 99,9% sure that `DOMContentLoaded` (when supported) will always fire before `load` regardless if there are images, iframes etc. available.

Comment: As @jAndy mentioned, yes, **onload** will fire after the **ready** event because **ready** is fired when the DOM is there and **onload** waits for all the assets (images etc) to load. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Just try it out for yourself: Create a large HTML file, strip every dependent resource (images, scripts, stylesheets) and test.

[image]

Load fires when every resource is fetched from the internet. DOMContentLoad fires when the HTML is fetched *and* parsed. The latter took 14 ms in my test with 140 KB HTML code. Sure, that's an edge case, but there is no guarantee that load fires before DOMContentLoaded - not even with external resources (due to caching, parallel downloads with HTTP/2, fast connections).

Comment: Did you also try it with `console.log`? Or are you relying solely on the developer tools UI?

Comment: That's the result of the developer tools which should be more precise than JavaScript that has to be parsed, compiled, and executed. Interestingly, I saw this effect only in Chromium-based browsers, not in Edge or Firefox.

Comment: Tests with console.log actually fire onload after DOMContentLoaded, also in Chromium. I wouldn't rely on that anyway.